# Mapping a field's values before sorting

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to sort my data in ElasticSearch using a field `customer_priority` that has the values: `IMMEDIATE`, `HIGH`, `MEDIUM`, `LOW`.

As the sort happens alphabetically, I'm getting the following undesired ordering: `HIGH`, `IMMEDIATE`, `LOW`, `MEDIUM`. But I would like: `LOW`, `MEDIUM`, `HIGH`, `IMMEDIATE`.

How can I instruct ElasticSearch to sort in an arbitrary way?

Some things I have investigated:

- I saw there is something called [custom scoring functions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) that you put in your queries, but is it actually the way to go? I'd like something I can put in the mapping instead of the query.
- Changing the actual stored value so it's a number instead of a string: I'd like to avoid this for the moment, it would require a big change in our systems.

BTW: I'm using ES 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script base sorting is the main option but it has several downsides. See [this documentation for how to sort with a script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) (I'm assuming you're using the newest ES version 5.3 at this time).

You would add something like this for your case:

```
"sort" : {
    "_script" : {
        "type" : "number",
        "script" : {
            "lang": "painless",
            "inline": "def val = doc['customer_priority'].value;                           
                       if (val == 'LOW') { return 0;} 
                       if (val == 'MEDIUM') {return 1;} 
                       if (val == 'HIGH') {return 2;} 
                       if (val == 'IMPORTANT') {return 3;}"
        },
        "order" : "asc"
    }
}
```

Note: I didn't test this code sample.

The downsides are you will need to enable fielddata for this field `customer_priority` in your mapping which will increase your memory requirement. It is not enabled by default. But luckily the cardinality of this field is small (just 4 values) so the overhead is small. The other downside is that script sorting is slow as the script needs to run on each document.

Another option might be to denormalize `customer_priority` further by adding a number field of `customer_priority_sort` which has a value of 1, 2, 3, or 4 and maps to `LOW`, `MEDIUM`, `HIGH`, and `IMPORTANT` so you can then sort on this value instead of the strings.

You'd have to keep the fields in sync if they change which is extra overhead but you might be happier with the results and would be step towards just storing an integer for these enumerated values instead of the strings directly which is more disk efficient anyway.

EDIT: for ES 2.3, groovy is the preferred scripting language so you might have to update the `Painless` code sample above but the approach is the same. Script based sorting is supported just the same in 2.3 and 5.3, see [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting).

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using ES 2.3, will update my question.

Comment: Is it possible to set this custom sorting as the default to that field so I don't need to pass it to the query each time (I'm thinking of defining it in the mapping for that field for example)

Comment: You can store a script and reference it by name in the query. See here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/modules-scripting.html#_indexed_scripts

Comment: Also, I didn't address it directly but you don't want to use custom scoring to imitate sorting.